# How to use the MySQL count() function in QT?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I want to get the total number of rows in a table. How can I achieve this?

I wrote the code as follows:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("localhost");
db.setDatabaseName("Dictionary");
db.setUserName("root");
db.setPassword("cinesoft");
bool ok = db.open();

int ID;
//SELECT COUNT(*) FROM icecream
QString IDnosql="SELECT * FROM Dictionary.TABLE_ENGLISH";

if(ok)
{
    QSqlQuery IDquery(db);
    IDquery.prepare(IDnosql);
    int Id=IDquery.numRowsAffected();
    IDquery.exec();

    // int Id=IDquery.numRowsAffected();
    QMessageBox::information(0,"sucess",QString::number(Id));
}
```

I use the count command. I want to get the total no of rows in my table and store to an integer variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just use the query `SELECT COUNT(*) from Dictionary.TABLE_ENGLISH` - this will give you the number of rows in the table. Then get this value from the result set and store it in an integer variable.

Answer (score 6):

You can prepare a `QSqlQuery` with the `COUNT` command:

```
 QSqlQuery q;
 q.prepare(QString("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM %1").arg(tableName));
 q.exec();
 int rows= 0;
 if (q.next()) {
        rows= q.value(0).toInt();
 }
```

Check [`QSqlQuery`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqlquery.html) for more details

Answer (score 1):

When using a COUNT statement, you can use QSqlQuery::value( int index ) like when selecting a single value:

```
QString IDnosql="SELECT COUNT( * ) FROM Dictionary.TABLE_ENGLISH";

if(ok)
{
    QSqlQuery IDquery(db);
    IDquery.prepare(IDnosql);

    if( !IDquery.exec() )
    {
        // TODO: perform error handling here!
    }
    if( !IDquery.next() )
    {
        // TODO: Error handling: Query did not return a result (no row, which should not be possible when using a count statement as you would always get 1 row)
    }

    int Id = IDquery.value( 0 ).toInt();

    QMessageBox::information(0,"sucess",QString::number(Id));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the total number of rows in a table `A` you simply

```
SELECT count(*) from A;
```

Then you need to convert the result to an integer.